# EF5 code first migrations byte[] column

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to create a data model that will work on both SQL Server 2008/2012 and SQLCE4. The problem i have is with binary data columns.

SQLCE requires use of the 'image' column type, but this is deprecated in SQL Server 2012.

If I declare a property as just:

```
byte[] Content { get; set; }
```

that's fine in SQL Server but fails for SQLCE
consequently if i declare it as:

```
[Column(TypeName = "image")]
byte[] Content { get; set; }
```

it works for CE now, but not for SQL server!

Is there some way to get this to work for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 
    `[MaxLength]`

That will work both for SQL Server and SQL Server Compact